# Elasticsearch - Cannot find nested type on path_route

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, amazon-emr, elasticsearch-5

Error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: [nested] nested object under path [path_route] is not of nested type. The same code works perfectly on another pc.

```
GET content/_search
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "path_route",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "path_route.status": [
                                        "approved"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        ]

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such errors messages aren't made up. You'll need to verify that `path_route` is truly of the `nested` type.

Run `GET content/_mapping` and verify it looks similar to this:

```
{
  "content": {
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "path_route": {
            "type": "nested",         <-------
            "properties": {
              "status": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If it isn't, specify it as such:

```
PUT /content
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "path_route": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "status": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```